# How do i remove duplicate valeus in push?

Tags: go, duplicates

This might be noob question...

How to remove the duplicate values instead pushing values?

When the values was:`("lorem", "ipsum", 1, 1, 1, "jack", "jill", "felix", "donking")`
It should print:`("lorem", "ipsum", 1, "jack", "jill", "felix", "donking")`

How to remove this duplicated  values in push function like above?

```
// Push values
func (q *Data) Push(n interface{}) *Data {
    if q.Len() < q.size {
        q.data = append(q.data, n)
        if q.data[q.Len()] == q.data[q.Len()+1] {
            q.Pop()
            q.Push(n)
        }
    } else {
        q.Pop()
        q.Push(n)
    }
    return q
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a list-like datastructure that removes duplicate values?

Comment: I am trying to make unique queue. Which removing incoming duplicate values.
For example was data above, which i need to remove incoming 1 to make it unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every data structure uses an underlying primitive data structure for implementation, and it looks like you are using a slice. If you only want to save unique data, you should use a `map`. In order to be as efficient as possible when using a map only for finding duplicates, you can use a `map[interface{}]struct{}`.

Comment: [My Code](https://go.dev/play/p/m5QOeSFTgyP)
This was my code. I am still figuring out about how i can inject to kick duplicate values code that.

Comment: you should add a map as i've stated before, and when you insert a new value in your `Push` method, check if that map contains that value, if so, don't insert it, if not, insert it.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to check the data in the queue against the pushed value. If the data was already in the queue it should returned.

```golang
for i := range q.data {
    if q.data[i] == n {
        return q // return q when n value is found equal to one of q.data values.
    }
}
q.data = append(q.data, n)
```